# Importing CSV files to access using VB or Batch

Tags: vba, csv, batch-file, ms-access, import

I have a bunch of excel files that need to imported into MS access tables everyday. I was looking for a way to automate this using Batch or VB. Is this possible using batch only? If not, how do i come about doing this with vb, i have no experience with vb and have no clue where to start. Can vb scripts be written on access only or requires any other programs?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA will best suited for this task. Every MS Offfice program have developer section on the ribbon (but you have to enable it), where you can enter VBA editor and wirte scripts there.